# Get batch size inside custom tensorflow keras metric

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to make a custom metric as in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#specifying_a_loss_metrics_and_an_optimizer

My code looks like this

```
class IOU(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
def __init__(self, name='iou_part', **kwargs):
    super(IOU, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.iou = self.add_weight(name='iou_part', initializer='zeros')

    self.template_width = 115
    self.template_height = 75

    self.frame_width = 1280
    self.frame_height = 720

    self.corners = tf.constant([[-0.5, 0.1], [-0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)

    self.epsilon = 1e-6

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
    fake_frame = tf.ones((batch_size, 1, self.frame_height, self.frame_width))
    fake_template = tf.ones((batch_size, 1, self.template_height, self.template_width))

    target = get_perspective_transform(self.corners, tf.reshape(y_true, (-1, 2, 4)))
    output = get_perspective_transform(self.corners, tf.reshape(y_pred, (-1, 2, 4)))

## Compute IOU
```

However this gives the error 'TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type 'NoneType' instead.' This is because y_true is (None, 4, 2) when model.compile(....) is executed. What is the correct way to get the batch size into the metric?

Comment: Use `tf.shape(y_true)[0]` instead of `y_true.shape[0]`

Comment: @Susmit Agrawal yes it works. Can you say why it works and why y_true.shape[0] does not work? tf.shape() returns strided_slice:0 while y_true.shape[0] returns NoneType.